# Why is my Troy-Bilt 5500 watt generator blowing exhaust back through the carb and muffler? If its a backfire, then its doing it on every stroke!

Tags: generator

I've checked the valve gap and all is well but on every stroke I have exhaust coming back through the carb. Not just a little, almost as if it were the muffler! Engine runs rough obviously and stumbles hard with the filter on until it eventually dies but with it off, it continues to run and run loud with this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the muffler and exhaust for obstructions? Something might have crawled up there.

Comment: Would check the timing also.  Valves might not be closing enough also, if you found gap needed more adjustment than normal.

Comment: If the engine won't run properly with the air filter on, it has more serious issues.  Are you trying to start it with the load connected?

Comment: Have you measured the compression? Is the intake valve sticking or otherwise not sealing? Is the valve lash set properly at TDC on the compression stroke?